# S3 Lifecycle cleanup exclude last deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lifecycle

I've got a lifecycle config for an S3 bucket which cleans up deployments after 180 days and I want to exclude the latest deployment but I have no idea how to do this. There is no exclude filter and it seems like aws will prefer shorter expiration times so I may can't overwrite it with a longer time. In our project we deploy pull requests to s3:///pr-<pr#>-<build#> and master builds like s3:///master-<build#>
So when deploying master-80 I want the master-79 and below folders to be deleted after 180 days after creation but master-80 should never be deleted until there is a newer deployment. The bucket policy is updated with every deployment so I can change it and apply new rules matching new folders.

Here is my current Bucket config

```
Bucket:
  Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
  Properties:
    BucketName: "{{{COMPONENT}}}-{{{ENVIRONMENT}}}"
    LifecycleConfiguration:
      Rules:
        - Id: 'Discard old PR deployments'
          ExpirationInDays: 7
          Prefix: 'pr-'
          Status: Enabled
        - Id: 'Move old deployments to cheaper storage'
          Status: Enabled
          Transitions:
            - StorageClass: 'INTELLIGENT_TIERING'
              TransitionInDays: 14
        - Id: 'Discard old results after 6 months'
          Status: Enabled
          ExpirationInDays: 180
```

Do you have any idea how to exclude the last build from cleanup? Thanks upfront.

Comment: you could just only have a `master` (without postfix) and enable versioning in S3 and create a lifecycle rule that removes old versions of the same file.

Comment: My fault not mentioning I have a 2nd deployment step to switch traffic to the new deployment. So with versioning I would get rid of this kind of important step which is not intended.